# There exists $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathrm{grad} f = g$.

Tags: vector-analysis

I want to know whether this is true :

> For all function $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2$ of class
> $\mathcal{C}^1$ there exists $f : \mathbb{R}^2  \rightarrow 
> > \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathrm{grad} f = g$.

I can't prove it is true, but I can't prove it is false with a counter-example either. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $f$ would be $C^2$ and hence the Hessian symmetric.

Comment: A necessary condition is curl(g)=0.